When landing Jupiter Swap transaction i'm getting error: "Program Error: "Instruction #1 Failed - Fallback functions are not supported"
can anyone help me in adding the compute limit and compute price in a transaction using Python?
I'm trying to add both instructions (compute limit and compute price) to the Jupiter Swap transaction that I get from their V6 API (swapTransaction_to_input in the code below). My transaction lands but with this error "Program Error: "Instruction #1 Failed - Fallback functions are not supported". The code that i'm using is the following:
rawTransaction=VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swapTransaction_to_input))

priorityFee = set_compute_unit_price(10000) accountKeys = rawTransaction.message.account_keys lengthAccountKeys = len(accountKeys)

for i in range(len(accountKeys)):
    if accountKeys[i]==Pubkey.from_string('ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111'):
        index_ComputeBudge=i+1
        print(i,index_ComputeBudge,accountKeys[i])

rawInstructions = rawTransaction.message.instructions

priorityInstruction = [CompiledInstruction(
    program_id_index=index_ComputeBudge, #antes lengthAccountKeys
    data=priorityFee.data,
    accounts=rawInstructions[0].accounts, )]

computeUnitLimit = set_compute_unit_limit(300000)

computeUnitLimitInstruction = CompiledInstruction(
    program_id_index=index_ComputeBudge, #antes lengthAccountKeys
    data=computeUnitLimit.data,
    accounts=rawInstructions[0].accounts, )

address_table_lookups_old=rawTransaction.message.address_table_lookups priorityInstruction.append(computeUnitLimitInstruction)

for i in range(len(rawInstructions)):
    priorityInstruction.append(rawInstructions[i]) ix=priorityInstruction

num_required_signatures=rawTransaction.message.header.num_required_signatures num_readonly_signed_accounts=rawTransaction.message.header.num_readonly_signed_accounts num_readonly_unsigned_accounts=rawTransaction.message.header.num_readonly_unsigned_accounts header={'header':{'num_required_signatures':num_required_signatures,
        'num_readonly_signed_accounts':num_readonly_signed_accounts,
        'num_readonly_unsigned_accounts':num_readonly_unsigned_accounts }}

header_AM=message.MessageHeader(num_required_signatures=num_required_signatures,
        num_readonly_signed_accounts=num_readonly_signed_accounts,
        num_readonly_unsigned_accounts=num_readonly_unsigned_accounts+1 ) 
newTransactionMessage = MessageV0(
         header=header_AM,
         account_keys=accountKeys,
         recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash_input,
         instructions=ix,
         address_table_lookups=address_table_lookups_old )

